# Как получить результат функции из БД?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть функция в БД MySQL, которая считает сумму покупки.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `Count`() RETURNS int
    DETERMINISTIC
begin
    DECLARE num int; 
    set num = (SELECT   SUM(p.Price*chek.Quantity) as Total
FROM  pos_product.chek,product p  
Where  Product_id= p.id );
    RETURN num;
end
```

[image: Это результат работы функции]

И теперь вопрос как это получить из БД?

```
using (pos_productContext db = new pos_productContext())
{
    try
    {
        ProductList = db.Products.ToList();
        ClientList = db.Clients.ToList();
       
        ChekList = db.Cheks.FromSqlRaw("SELECT product.id,product.Image, product.Title,product.Price,chek.Product_id ,chek.Quantity FROM chek  left join pos_product.product  on chek.Product_id = product.id;  ").ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }    
}
```

Пробовал выводить, везде было null.
Пробовал FromSqlRaw и др. методы.

Comment: Вы используете Entity Framework, но при этом упорно пишете сырые SQL-запросы. Выберите что-то одно.

Comment: И ради всего святого, переименуйте `chek`.

Comment: Я вам ранее уже писал: метод `FromSqlRaw` возвращает `IQueryable<T>` - **коллекцию** сущностей. Вы упорно пытаетесь его применить для получения **одного** значения.

Comment: Можете использовать [ExecuteSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw). Он вызывается у свойства `DbContext.Database`. Результат вовзращать через параметр с `ParameterDirection.Output`, как показано здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46163876/5045688. Или используйте обычный ADO.NET, как показано по той же ссылке в другом ответе.

Comment: Я раньше писал на Net framefork с использованием mysql.Перешел на EF Core  из-за упрощения кода .Вот почему я пытаюсь использовать приемы из Net Framework .Я просто пробую ,LINQ тоже пробывал но как с помощью него выводить допустим сложные запросы или функции

Answer (score 0):

Оформите это не как функцию, а как хранимую процедуру:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Count`()
SELECT SUM(p.Price*chek.Quantity) AS Total
FROM pos_product.chek
JOIN product p ON chek.Product_id = p.id;
```

И теперь выполняйте

```
CALL `Count`;
```

словно это обычный SELECT-запрос. В ответ вернёт набор записей с одной записью из одного поля Total.

Comment: Спасибо но как это отобразить в Label? и какой метод использовать  ? FromSqlRaw? ChekList = db.Cheks.FromSqlRaw

Comment: @Ученик *как это отобразить в Label?* Отображение данных - это отдельная задача, никак не связанная с их получением. Создайте новый вопрос.